# Is there anyway I can make a plane visible from both sides?

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, blender, low-poly

In Unity i have a model of a tree with leaves made of a plane and a texture, when I upload it to unity the texture is only visible on one side so how can I change it to be visible from both sides without increasing the polygons. And I am not familiar with complicated shader programming and stuff so could you please explain in detail. Thanks I'm advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning off backface culling.

In your shader, put "Cull Off" in the "SubShader" section.

Comment: You mean I just write "Cull Off" between the SubShader brackets?

Comment: @VadimTatarnikov that's right.